# laravel - get subtotal from rows having similar column values under another column with same values

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

The DB has a table namely `records`. Among the fields are `product_id`,`quantity`,`store_id`.

I need to get the sum total of quantity of those rows which belong to a certain `store_id` and then have same `product_id` values.

For example , the table has values : (2,3,4),(2,1,5),(<s>1</s>  2,2,4) Then I need to get the sum total of `quantity` along with other columns from 1st and 3rd rows. And the 2nd row will also be present in the result.

Let us assume the Controller name to be `RecordController` and the model name to be `Record`.

How should I write the query ?

Edit :  the table has values : (2,3,4),(2,1,5),(<s>1</s>  2,2,4)

Comment: So you want to get the `count` of a `quantity` grouped by `product_id` where `store_id`?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, For a certain `store_id`, the query will look up for same `product_ids` and then will add the `quantity` from those rows. Other columns should also be available

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich, See my edit

Comment: Confusing description over there

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich, I want `product_id`=2, `quantity`=(3+2), `store_id`=4. And again `product_id`=2, `quantity`=1,  `store_id`=5  from the 2nd row.

Comment: @Sagar, still confusing after the `Edit`?

Comment: You can do by grouping record by product_id and raw query to sum the quantity for specific store_id

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed you need to use `groupBy()` clause on `produt_id` & `store_id` to get the desired result. I have written the query in my answer please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a single query.

**Try This:-**

```
DB::table('records')
    ->select('product_id',DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity'),'store_id')
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->groupBy('store_id')
    ->get();
```

**Explanation:**
This query will fetch all the records & group them by `product_id` & `store_id` so will only get a single row for a single product in the store. And then it will display the `sum` of `quantity` in the output.

**Update:-**

**Using ORM:-**

```
\App\YourModelName::select('product_id',DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity'),'store_id')
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->groupBy('store_id')
    ->get();
```

But you need to write the raw query in any case, it can't be done using default ORM functionality

Comment: How to write the query using ORM ?

Comment: How to get other columns besides the 3 in the query ?

Comment: can we use `DB::raw` in ORM ?

Comment: To get any other column, just add their comma seperated names in the `select` clause and yes we can use `DB::raw` in ` ORM, if required